# Rails 5: Adding bootstrap killed my javascript files in heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I built a demo app to demonstrate simple infinite scroll. I built it with zero css and styling and deployed it to heroku and it works as expected.

To spruce it up, I decided to incorporate bootstrap so the table is larger and you don't have to shrink the window to hit the scroll event. However, adding bootstrap seemed to kill all javascript in my app. Here is a copy of the demo app with bootstrap included:

https://tranquil-taiga-22790.herokuapp.com/

The code is identical aside from what you need to change in application.js in order to include `bootstrap-sprockets`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
console.log("works with bootstrap?");
```

As you can see I've included a test message which doesn't show up at all. I also tried putting `require bootstrap-sprockets` between the two `jquery` requires and still nothing. Here is the specific js file I'm trying to execute:

```
$(function() {
  console.log("anything?");
  if ($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
    return $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      var more_posts_url;
      console.log('scroll?');
      more_posts_url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
      if (more_posts_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
        console.log('hit');
        $('.pagination').html('<p>Loading...</p>');
        $.getScript(more_posts_url);
      }
      return;
    });
  }
});
```

I should note that the bootstrap version of the app works perfectly on my local machine, something is happening when it's going up to production in heroku.

Edit: This isn't a satisfactory answer but I recreated the exact same application only using the `bootstrap-sass` gem with BS3 (not the `bootstrap` gem using BS4 alpha like in this original question) and everything works in production. This leads me to believe it is a BS issue exclusively.

Comment: Try something that removes all the installation difficulty, at least until you understand how to use the asset pipeline effectively: https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass/versions/3.3.6

Comment: Can you clarify? I am using the bootstrap official gem so that I can use BS4 the bootstrap-sass gem only supports 3

Comment: The js console has this error `Bootstrap tooltips require Tether`

Comment: Tether is only for tooltips. I am not using tool tips it's just a BS4 error that hasn't been resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I put the following in my gem file and everything worked fine. Not sure if it will work the same for you but figured it's worth a shot...

```
# use scss for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# make everything pretty with boostrap by twitter
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
# needed for popups and tooltips to work
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.3.3'
end
```

Comment: As @Iceman mentioned above, tether may be the missing link which is what I have in my gemfile...

Comment: The issue isn't tether Tether is only for tooltips which BS4 requires. I am not using tool tips. Bootstrap is killing all javascript in the app.

Comment: Hm... I'm wondering, have you tried putting your js in a new js file and then require that file in the application.js file?

Comment: I've played around with that by removing the specific .js file and adding the javascript I need directly to application.js but it doesn't work. I can't even get a console.log message to execute. Again, all javascript seems to have been killed unless it's inside <script> tags. I can't even get a console.log message to post inside of the .js.erb file. Again, everything works fine in development.

Comment: Odd... I'm not sure if I can assist... I haven't heard of something like that happening. Just to confirm, which bootstrap version have you specified in your gemfile? I'm wondering if it's a new bug somewhere...